# Why does deserialization of nested dictionary throws an exception in C# but works in F#?

Tags: c#, exception, f#, json.net, deserialization

I serialize a F# record type to Json with Newtonsoft.Json.FSharp.

```
type Prices =  Dictionary<string, decimal>

type PriceList = {Id:string; Name:string; Date:DateTime; CurrencySymbol:string; Status:Status; Prices:Prices}

let private converters : JsonConverter array =
  [| BigIntConverter();
    GuidConverter();
    ListConverter();
    OptionConverter();
    MapConverter();
    TupleArrayConverter();
    UnionConverter();
    UriConverter();
    CultureInfoConverter() |]

let private settings = JsonSerializerSettings (
                        Converters = converters,
                        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)

let serialize obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings)
```

The result in JSON is this:

```
{
  "Id": "PriceList20140201",
  "Name": "PriceList",
  "Date": "2014-02-01T00:00:00+01:00",
  "CurrencySymbol": "€",
  "Status": 0,
  "Prices": {
    "ItemCodeA": 512.4,
    "ItemCodeB": 471.0
  }
}
```

And if I deserialize this it works fine

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceList>(text)
```

Result in F# Interactive:

```
val y : PriceList =
{Id = "PriceList20140201";
Name = "PriceList";
Date = 01.04.2014 00:00:00;
CurrencySymbol = "€";
Status = Sale;
Prices =
 dict
   [("ItemCodeA", 512.4M); ("ItemCodeB", 471.0M);...];}
```

Now I want to deserialize it in C# using Newtonsoft.Json

```
public class PriceList
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public Prices Prices { get; set; }
}

public class Prices : Dictionary<string, decimal>
{
}
...
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceList>(json)
```

This results in an JsonSerializationException:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'Halep.Logic.OfferManagement.Contracts.DataClasses.Pricing.Prices'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a
>   JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to
>   an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g.
>   ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array. Path 'Prices', line 7, position 13.

I read that I need a CustomConverter for nested dictionaries. But as far as I know it should be possible since version 6.0.? without a custom converter. I'm currently using 8.0.3.
Why does it work in F# but not in C#? Is the C# object structure wrong?

I tried to replace PriceList directly with Dictionary but same result.

**Update** 
The last sentence means I tried this:

```
public class PriceList
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

And got nearly the same Exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Decimal]'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a
>   JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to
>   an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g.
>   ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array. Path 'Prices', line 7, position 13.

**Update 2: Solution**
This code works.  The last comment of @JustinNiessner led to the solution. The problem was that the input was in fact this which contains [ ] instead of { }:

```
{
  "Id": "PriceList20140201",
  "Name": "PriceList",
  "Date": "2014-02-01T00:00:00+01:00",
  "CurrencySymbol": "€",
  "Status": 0,
  "Prices": [
    "ItemCodeA": 512.4,
    "ItemCodeB": 471.0
  ]
```

}

Comment: What is the JSON object which you try to deserialzie to PriceList? PriceList is not a list in your sample code, so you won't be able to deserialize a collection into a type which has nothing to do with a collection.

Comment: I try to deserialize the second code snippet which is the result of the serialization with F#. PriceList is just the type in F#  / the class in C#

Comment: Your F# code uses Dictionary, your C# code uses Prices.  Make it Dictionary as well.

Comment: @HansPassant - Copy-cat. Haha.

Comment: @HansPassant But it doesn't work. See below

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem -- your c# code deserializes your JSON correctly.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/hnyKKA.  Is there any chance you are using an F#-specific collection converter for c#?  For instance, in [`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/p_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert_defaultsettings.htm)?

Comment: @KCT - Your update doesn't make sense. The JSON that you posted has no Arrays in it, yet the error you posted says that you're trying to deserialize an Array. The JSON you posted must be different than what you're actually trying to deserialize.

Comment: As far as I can see the above code is missing the definition for the Enum Status. If I change that to int in the class definition, the above code works perfectly.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Your last comment is completly right! It doen't make sense and the problem was the input that I thought I've checked it twice. The code in my question works perfectly (even with derived Prices from Dictionary that I learned is something different than atype abbreviation) if I do not use [ ] in one of my samples for Prices instead of { }. Lesson learned: Don't try to solve problems in the evening and save a some hours of work. Thanks for all your effort bringing me on track again.

Answer (score 5):

`type Prices = Dictionary<string, decimal>` is a type abbreviation in F# rather than creating a new class that inherits from `Dictionary<string, decimal>` as the C# code does:

[F# Type Abbreviations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233246.aspx)

That is why you're seeing deserialization differences between the two.

There are two ways that you can fix this in C#. The first would be to create a similar type alias with the `using` directive:

```
using Prices = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>;
```

The other would be to simply replace the type with `Decimal<string, decimal>` in the `PriceList` class definition:

```
public class PriceList
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

And then the C# Desserialization will work the same way as the F#.

Comment: Yes, that means that Prices is used instead of Dictionary<string, decimal>. I do the same in C# as far as I understand it. Just by deriving the class from the dictionary. Anyway I can ask the question the other way around. What is the C# objectstructure to deserialize the second snippet (json)? I think Prices should be a Dictionary<string, decimal>. Unfortunatly it doesn't work

Comment: @KCT - Inheriting from `Decimal<string, decimal>` and creating a new child type is very different than just aliasing the parent type with a different name. Just because you inherit from `Decimal<string, decimal>` doesn't guarantee that it can be deserialized the same way.

Comment: @KCT - Either way, I've updated my answer with the equivalent C# alias.

Comment: @ Thanks for updating your answer. As I said I tried exactly the code that your wrote in your second snippet. But that throws (nearly) the same excepetion: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Decimal]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. ...

Comment: I updated my question to clarify that I tried this but this does not work but thanks for having a look at it.